# Partition "" is not valid for resource arn::s3:::stackset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

We are seeing following ERROR when pipeline running and it got roll back

```
Partition "" is not valid for resource "arn::s3:::stackset-test-qa-infrastr-pipelinebuiltartifactbuc-1hh4rg3lyds4u/manual/f4063f9663d8d3fb600862222ddf947a61d0ac414a20284b2436336ed4f5/bootstrap.env". (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 2b0dg80e-c952-49e8-8e16-e1c7c4009860; Proxy: null)
```

Any idea how to fix this Thanks

Comment: by putting e.g. `aws` in between the first and second `:` (or aws-cn, or something related to gov or iso)

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 fixed issue by manually updating the file and working good

Answer (score 0):

Your specified ARN is missing `aws` between the first and second `:`.